# Predicting DXL Memory and CPU Usage

Tags: memory, cpu, profile, predict, ibm-doors

Has anyone had any success in predicting or profiling DXL applications for memory and CPU usage?

I have a script that opens, closes, and modifies modules, possibly hundreds or even thousands of modules. I want to know, or least have a rough idea, how many modules I can run through the script before running out of memory.

Cross posts:

http://smartdxl.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=602

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=c5d4cc33-9986-463e-a73b-36523e6add7a&ps=25

Comment: You cannot assume all modules have similar memory & CPU usage.

Comment: If you are properly closing each module after processing it, then you should not run into memory issues. The thing that generally causes problems is the opening of linked modules for related information. The linked modules are typically forgotten and stay open, chewing up your resources. If you post some of your code perhaps we can help.

Comment: IMHO you're mixing things up. There is memory consumption because of opening modules and there is memory consumption by executing DXL code. I never got into problems because of executing DXL. Most of the time big modules or a big number of open modules led to insufficient memory. This applies to DOORS 8.3. Which version are you interested in?